# Populating each column simultaneously

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

When I run this code

```
UPDATE #NDD  
SET #NDD.[2018-07-31] = mh.NextDueDate 
FROM #MARS_history as mh
WHERE mh.Account = #NDD.Account

SELECT * FROM #NDD
```

I get this:

[image]

Which is great, but I would like to do this for all the other columns as well in a sort of for loop or something. I am new to SQL so I am not sure how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add more columns to the `set` clause.

Something like this:

```
UPDATE #NDD  
   SET #NDD.[2018-07-31] = mh.NextDueDate,
       #NDD.[2018-06-30] = mh.NextDueDate,
       #NDD.[2018-05-31] = mh.NextDueDate
  FROM #MARS_history as mh
 WHERE mh.Account = #NDD.Account
```

Comment: What is the syntax?